# Hosting a "naked domain redirect" server

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, nameserver

I've got a DNS server running at "dns.u4ik.us" I have full control of the Apache server www.u4ik.us (same server as dns.uik.us) and the dns records themselves. I wanted to supply a service where people would type 96.245.253.143 into their example.com A record, and when someone accessed the site, would redirect to www.example.com (set to their actual IP). Essentially the same thing as WWWizer.com. Would I configure this in Apache or my DNS?

Comment: +1 for the idea, I thought about this myself a few weeks ago but never got round to it.

Comment: @samarudge likewise - the real problem is getting yourself an IP that you can guarantee won't ever be revoked, since every single client of the service must (by definition) use the naked IP, and not a DNS name.

Comment: @Alnitak Hmm hadn't thought about that. also could be a lot of traffic and no way to promote/monetize the service. Still it's one of those "It would make it easier, but I can't be bothered" kind of things =)

Comment: @samarudge yeah, tricky, especially when there's PCI compliance to sort out... ;-)

Comment: *cough* Just going to leave this here and hope *someone* finds it useful http://apache-range-exploit.com/

Comment: @chris s - Thanks, but my servers are secure. The IP above was changed a time back, and the www.u4ik.us site is proxied through a random server on the net. But it was interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be configured in Apache, set up a virtual host to listen on that IP (with no other VHosts listening) then use a rewrite rule to redirect.

Something along the lines of

```
<VirtualHost 96.245.253.143:80>
ServerName redirector
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
<Location />
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301] 
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

(Note: Code not tested, guessing from memory but it should be something along those lines)

Comment: Thanks. What if, perhaps, I set up the thing to listen for "redirect.u4ik.us" port 80, where the user sets their site to go to CNAME redirect.u4ik.us instead of the A-name to my IP? Would I then be able to host a site there as well?

Comment: I don't think you can use CNames on naked domains (Might be wrong). But you could host multiple sites on that IP so long as the redirector was the first virtual host defined (I.E. the default). VirtualHosts work on the host header sent by the browser, not the DNS records.

Comment: Yes, Apache will pick up the request for the domain, then look for the corresponding virtual host. I do think (not sure 100%) that you can set the CNAME as the root of a domain. As long as there are no A-records as the root.

Comment: Okay, I think i got it. They will now enter the IP as their root A record. Unless my local cache is not up to date, It should be working. Thanks for your help.